# merge row values based on "if empty or not"

Tags: excel, vba

Actually I have converted a pdf to excel. After conversion the next line is converted in next row. I want to merge contents on following condition.

If row1 & row2 has text then put contents of row2 in row1 (in addition to existing) and clear contents of row2. If row2 is blank it should keep contents of row1 and move on to next row.

I have tried two macros. But they are not giving desired output

```
Sub cc()
Dim X As Integer

For X = 1 To 500
 'If Sheet2.Cells(X + 1, 1)  isNotBlank Then
 If Not IsEmpty(Sheet2.Cells(X + 1, 1).Value) And Not IsEmpty(Sheet2.Cells(X, 1).Value) Then
 
    Sheet2.Cells(X + 1, 1).ClearContents
  End If
 
Next

End Sub

Sub ccc()
Dim X As Integer

For X = 1 To 500
 'If Sheet2.Cells(X + 1, 1)  isNotBlank Then
 If Not IsEmpty(Sheet2.Cells(X + 1, 1).Value) And Not IsEmpty(Sheet2.Cells(X, 1).Value) Then
    If Not IsEmpty(Sheet2.Cells(X, 1).Value) Then
        Sheet2.Cells(X, 1).Value = Sheet2.Cells(X, 1)
 
    Sheet2.Cells(X + 1, 1).ClearContents
  End If
 
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of `IsEmpty` I would use `Sheet2.Cells(X + 1, 1).Value <> vbNullString` or maybe even `Trim(Sheet2.Cells(X + 1, 1).Value) <> vbNullString`

Comment: Just noticed you're not merging the cells values.  You're missing `Sheet2.Cells(X, 1).Value = Sheet2.Cells(X, 1).Value & vbCrLf & Sheet2.Cells(X+1, 1).Value`.  Replace `vbCrLf` with something else if you don't want the new line.